# How to use Django's {% trans %} with Pug/Jade

Tags: python, django, pug

I'm using [pypugjs](https://github.com/matannoam/pypugjs) in my Django project, which is very very simillar to pyjade.

Below is a snippet from my `.pug` file:

```
H3 Bottle Form
form(method="post" action=".")
    | {% csrf_token %}
    | {{ form.as_p }}
    input(type="submit" value="{% trans 'Submit' %}")
```

No matter how I try to variate the `value` attribute for `input`, I get the following error:

> 'trans', expected 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this
>   tag?

Please note that I do have the following in my `base.html`, which the `.pug` file above extends:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}   // <-- import for trans tags
{% load compress %}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a minimal but complete django app available which demonstrates this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
{% load i18n %}
```

in every pug file, rather than only in `base.pug`.

Answer (score 0):

The load directives have to be present in every template where i18n is used, so just include

```
-load i18n
```

right below *extends*